# How to run Google Tag Manager script in a external .js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement Google Tag Manager but wish to put the code snippet provided from google in an external .js file that I can load. This is mainly due to the fact that it would be easier to maintain. Some code has to be placed in the header and some in the body.

**I have two questions:**

1. Is it possible to run the script from an external .js file, how would that script look?
2. Is it possible to run two functions from the same .js file? *Something along the lines of:*

```html
<!-- Let's assume I name the Google Tag Manager JavaScript file to "gtm.js" -->
<!-- The gtm.js contains two functions with one called head and another called body -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gtm.js, run function: head"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gtm.js, run function: body"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Google Tag Manager Head Code:**

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-xxxxxxx');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**Google Tag Manager Body Code:**

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxxxxxx"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: Its not required. You can simple put both code in yout html file itself. If you lool at the code. Its **self invoking function** . Once its put, script tags executed, it will call function and thrn done. You can pit in header script rag and other one at the end of body.  **noscript** only gets executed if your browser does not support JAVASCRIPT which is very unlikely case though

Comment: Hmm, interesting... so generally speaking if the browser supports scripts, the Google Tag Manager Body code is unnecessary?

Comment: Yes. Its either or. Just put both code. Eventually it will run one. Google is brand. They do need to provide alternative.

Comment: True, but it would be better to add it into .js file. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: Yoi can put script tag one code into one file. Put code **without** script tag. Name it lets say one.js and then simply tag that file in your html `<script src="one.js" />`